# How to link 3 RF transceivers to 1 antenna

Tags: rf, bluetooth, wifi

I'm not an RF designer, so excuse the newbie question:

How would I link three transceivers, say WiFi and two separate bluetooth transceivers, to a single antenna.

I have found a 3-way combiner https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/SCN-3-28.pdf

Is this the right circuit?

Is there a better method?

How bad is it that I'm loosing a lot of power - is there a way to mitigate this (amplifier, etc.)?

Comment: *I'm not an RF designer* Then you should be using a separate antenna for each device. Only when a system with multiple transceivers is designed to share one antenna would this work. What if the WiFi is transmitting while at the same time one of the Bluetooth transceivers is receiving. That would saturate the LNA of the BT receiver, possibly even damage it. If you were an RF designer you might be able to get this working by using circulators to direct the power in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

This should be enough  for the purpose, the power reduction will only reduce the distance but depends on how complex you want your circuit to be. To compensate this you would need amplifiers both for transmitter (PA) and receiver (LNA) chains.